# ajax Session in Generic Handler / Chrome problem

Tags: c#, ajax, session, google-chrome, ashx

I have an generic handler in C# (.ashx) that should read the Session Variables.
When sending a jQuery Ajax request to the generic handler, the Session variables are null.

I've tried to add IRequiresSessionState to the class, with no luck.
In IE everything works ok. But in Google Chrome I can not make it work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

jaan

Comment: How about sessions in general, does it work in other cases in chrome?

Comment: they work in other pages (aspx, even in services)   only not in ashx generic handlers

Answer (score 1):

Implement your handler with IRequiresSessionState like:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

get session value: `context.Session["xyz"]`